# Matlab GUI draw area size specification

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I used this to obtain and save a figure:

```
function sketch(cmd)
  if nargin == 0
      cmd = 'init';
  end

switch cmd
case 'init'
    fig = figure('DoubleBuffer','on','back','off');
    info.ax = axes('XLim',[0 1],'YLim',[0 1]);
    info.drawing = [];
    info.x = [];
    info.y = [];
    set(fig,'UserData',info,...
            'WindowButtonDownFcn',[mfilename,' down'])

case 'down'
    myname = mfilename;
    fig = gcbf;
    info = get(fig,'UserData');
    curpos = get(info.ax,'CurrentPoint');
    info.x = curpos(1,1);
    info.y = curpos(1,2);
    info.drawing = line(info.x,info.y,'Color','k');
    set(fig,'UserData',info,...
            'WindowButtonMotionFcn',[myname,' move'],...
            'WindowButtonUpFcn',[myname,' up'])

case 'move'
    fig = gcbf;
    info = get(fig,'UserData');
    curpos = get(info.ax,'CurrentPoint');
    info.x = [info.x;curpos(1,1)];
    info.y = [info.y;curpos(1,2)];
    set(info.drawing,'XData',info.x,'YData',info.y)
    set(fig,'UserData',info)

case 'up'
    fig = gcbf;
    set(fig,'WindowButtonMotionFcn','',...
            'WindowButtonUpFcn','')
saveas(gcf, 'test.png');
export_fig test2.png
end
```

I want to fix the area size to 50x50 (50 pix,50pix) and without x-y axes.

I tried:

```
x0=500;
y0=500;
width=50;
height=50;
set(gcf,'position',[x0,y0,width,height])
```

However, it doesn't look good and saves the image as 120x50 pixels. How can I save the figure as 50x50 pixels instead?

Answer (score 0):

check out this function I wrote, it does exactly what you asked - plot a figure and export the image to a specified size

https://github.com/fangq/iso2mesh/blob/v1.9.2/img2mesh.m#L516-L535

the key is to set axis using this line

```
ax=axes('parent',gcf,'Units','pixels','position',[1, 1, imsize(1), imsize(2)]);
```

where the unit is pixels and axis width is resized to the desired pixel length via `position`. Once this is done, `getframe` will get the image.